# I want to search for users in my user model and search another database that contains values that the user owns, with Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to setup a site wide search that searches for users, as well as items belonging to users.

Basically each user has many "cereals", and I want to be able to keep the cereal hidden from the search results, and show the owner of the cereal in its place.

Right now I have sunspot functional, but on my index page in users, it lists all the users before a search is performed. If now search is performed I want the results to be empty.

I am still a noob to rails, and am trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my source.

App/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Amistad::FriendModel
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  has_many :cereals, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]


  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :phone, :urlname
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
  end

            def update_with_password(params={})
        current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

        if params[:password].blank?
          params.delete(:password)
          params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
        end

                result = if params[:password].blank? || valid_password?(current_password) 
          update_attributes(params)
        else
          self.attributes = params
          self.valid?
          self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
          false
        end

        clean_up_passwords
        result
            end

    searchable do
        text :firstname, :lastname, :username
    end

end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
        before_filter :authenticate_user!

        def index
            @search = User.search do
                fulltext params[:search]
            end
            @users = @search.results
      end

        def show
          if params[:id].nil? && current_user
            @user = current_user
          else
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
          end
          @cereal = current_user.cereals.build if signed_in?
          @cereals = @user.cereals.paginate(page: params[:page])
      end

      def first_time
          if params[:id].nil? && current_user
            @user = current_user
          else
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
          end
      end

        def edit
            if params[:id].nil? && current_user
                @user = current_user
            else
                @user = User.find(params[:id])
            end
      end

        def profile
            @username = params[:id]
            @friends = current_user.friends || []
            @title = "User Profile for #{@username}"
            @user = User.find_by_username(@username)
            @users = User.all :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]
      end 

    end
```

views/users/index.html.haml

```
= form_tag @users_path, :method => :get do
        %p
            = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
            = submit_tag "Search", name: 'nil'


    - @users.each do |user|
        %p
        = user.username
```